# Find rows by specific text using full text search in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I want to display the correct results when searching specific text using full-text search. I created a sample table and specific query for each requirement. Most queries below didn't return the expected value.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id INT identity, ftcol NVarChar(100))
GO

INSERT t1(ftcol) 
VALUES ('<field>hello</field>'), ('hello'), ('world'),
       ('hello again'), ('/hello/'), 
       ('Portals/1/'), ('Portals:1'), ('{"SpInitiatedSso')
GO

CREATE fulltext catalog cat1
GO

-- now create the view, must be schemabound view so it must explicitly
--specify columns and 2 part name for table
CREATE VIEW myview 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
     SELECT id, ftcol 
     FROM dbo.t1 
GO

-- create the index on the view to be used as full text key index
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx ON myview(id)
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON myview(ftcol) KEY INDEX idx ON cat1
GO

DECLARE @x nvarchar(100)='<field>hello</field>'

SELECT * 
FROM myview 
WHERE CONTAINS(ftcol, @x)     -- should return '<field>hello</field>'

DECLARE @x1 NVARCHAR(100)='Portals/1/'

SELECT * 
FROM myview 
WHERE CONTAINS(ftcol, @x1)    -- should return 'Portals/1/'

DECLARE @x2 nvarchar(100)='"hello again"'

SELECT * 
FROM myview 
WHERE CONTAINS(ftcol, @x2)    -- should return 'hello again'

DECLARE @x3 nvarchar(100)='/hello/'

SELECT * 
FROM myview 
WHERE CONTAINS(ftcol, @x3)    -- should return '/hello/'

DECLARE @x4 NVARCHAR(100)='"Portals:1"'

SELECT * 
FROM myview 
WHERE CONTAINS(ftcol, @x4)    --should return 'Portals:1'

DECLARE @x5 NVARCHAR(100)='{"SpInitiatedSso'

SELECT *
FROM myview 
WHERE CONTAINS(ftcol, @x5)    -- should return '{"SpInitiatedSso', throws error
```

UPDATE: I had have set the expected return value for each condition.

Comment: Please correct your variable mapping like in 2nd question you are declaring X3 but your select is having X1 . Is that correct or some typing mistake ?

Comment: @RajneeshVaishwar, sorry,  it's already updated.

Comment: Could you please add the actual result which you currently get for each case? For example, you said search for `'Portals/1/'` should return 1 record, but what is currently being returned for you?

Comment: @andrews, please see updated info. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, for the update, but it's not what I was asking about. I asked to specify what you actually had returned, what results did you get. Because, when running your queries against my instance I usually get more than 1 record returned, where you say should return 1 record. So do you have 0 results in most cases or you have 2 results but want only 1?

Comment: Hi @andrews, some query returns more than 1 records, some are not because of error(last query has an error so no value returned), it should return only the text that I am searching. Please see the expected return value above.